# Detect when a fragment is drawn?

Tags: android

Basically I need the functionality of `onWindowFocusChanged()` but on a `Fragment`.
The `onWindowFocusChanged()` listener isn't actually available to fragments unfortunately, so I'm not sure what to do.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Fragments are "drawn" via the `View` you return in `onCreateView()`.  You can use the event handlers in that.  Usually, if there's a command that needs to be run when the `View` first comes to view, you can assign it in a `Runnable` and attach it to the `View` via the `post()` method.

```
getView().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // code you want to run when view is visible for the first time
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Seems to be working right! I'm going to run it through some scenarios before I select this as the right answer.

Comment: I should also note (almost two months later), that this trick works on any View.  Not just the ones posted via Fragment, so if you inflate a View int he Activity for example. This will work.

Comment: Yes! Ive been using this all over for little view gimmicks I have going on, its great.

Comment: this returns null if the fragment sometimes... Maybe adding a eventlistener on the fragment?

Comment: If the fragment returns null, then `onCreateView()` will eventually be called so you can post a runnable to the view you turn there.  It will run as soon as the fragment draws.

Comment: Likewise, if you DO want an event listener, you can post a runnable to the view just before you return from `onCreateView()` which calls a custom method `onFirstDraw()` or something.

Answer (score 0):

onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) method calls in activity, but when fragment drawns we can check through method onActivitycreated(). Check this post  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32819850/2732632

Answer (score -3):

OnWindowFocusChanged doesn't provide info about drawing a view (or  didn't see)
Implement OnWindowFocusChanged on each view that can have focus in your Fragment. 
in pseudo-code:

```
Fragment implements OnWindowFocusChanged{

onCreate(){

btn.OnWindowFocusChanged(this);
editTxt.OnWindowFocusChanged(this);
....

}

public void OnWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
// your fragment has focus
}

}
```