# How can I get Width and Height of RelativeLayout

Tags: android-layout

I am not able to get width and height of RelativeLayout, how can I get this? My layout.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="50dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and I just get programtically height and width of RelativeLayout using its built-in provided method like,

```
public class CustomShowcaseActivity extends Activity {    static float width;
  static float height;  RelativeLayout relMain;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_showcase);

    relMain= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutMain);


    width = relMain.getMeasuredWidth();
      height = relMain.getMeasuredHeight();

    width = relMain.getWidth();
    height = relMain.getHeight();

    System.out.println("=== Width : " + width);
    System.out.println("=== height : " + height);

} }
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `override` this method first.

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        getRelativeLayoutInfo();
    }
```

> Try by using only `getHeight()` and `getWidth()`

```
 private void getRelativeLayoutInfo(){
    relMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutMain);
    w = relMain.getWidth();
    h = relMain.getHeight();
    Log.v("W-H", w+"-"+h);
 }
```

Comment: As u can see my above code i already use this but it will not working.

Comment: `Override` `onWindowFocusedChanged` see i have updated.

Comment: it's working perfectly a little more on that topic how can i achieve this in Fragment and also Adapter any idea ?

Comment: @ jaydroider if u really know about then inform me.

Comment: @GauravMandlik check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129984/how-to-get-the-onwindowfocuschanged-on-fragment and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254879/detect-when-a-fragment-is-drawn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113106/discussion-between-gaurav-mandlik-and-jaydroider).